# Is it possible to detect postal addresses in mobile safari so it can be added to contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ipad, mobile-safari

Is it possible to detect postal addresses in mobile safari on ios?

I have a mobile web application and thought it would be a nice feature if the ipad/iphone could detect addresses on the webpage and highlight them in the same way it is already doing for telephone numbers.

I may not have the address in the correct format for example or using the wrong tags around it.

Im using the

```
<address></address>
```

tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. According to the [**Safari HTML Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW5) the only data detection that Mobile Safari supports is telephone numbers.